# TypeError: props.setuserName is not a function at Login.js:29:1 at async loginUser (Login.js:21:1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

**TypeError: props.setuserName is not a function      at Login.js:29:1     at async loginUser (Login.js:21:1)**
**Parent Component, am passing arguments to the Login component**

```
// import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import About from "./MyComponent/About";
import { Header } from "./MyComponent/Header";
import { LoginSignup } from "./MyComponent/LoginSignup";
import { NotFound } from "./MyComponent/NotFound";
import { TodoDisplayBody } from "./MyComponent/TodoDisplayBody";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const [userid, setuserid] = useState(null);
  const [userName, setuserName] = useState(null);

  const [authenticated, setauthenticated] = useState(null);

  if (authenticated === null || authenticated === false) {
    return (
      <LoginSignup
        setauthenticated={setauthenticated}
        setuserid={setuserid}
        setuserName={setuserName}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header setauthenticated={setauthenticated} userName={userName} />
      <Routes>
        {/* <Route path="/login" element={<LoginSignup setuserid={setuserid} />} /> */}
        <Route index element={<TodoDisplayBody userid={userid} />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/notfound" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**The Login Component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import loginSignupCSS from "./css/LoginSignup.module.css";

const Login = (props) => {
  //=================For log into todo  list=================================
  const [email, setemail] = useState("");
  const [password, setpassword] = useState("");

  const [inputType, setinputType] = useState("password");

  const [isView, setisView] = useState(false);

  //When userclickes on login button loginUser() method will be invoked
  const loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!email || !password) {
      alert("Email and password field cant be blanked");
    } else {
      await axios
        .post(`http://localhost:8082/loginuser`, {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        })
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.data.name);
          props.setuserid(result.data.id);
          props.setuserName(result.data.name); //Here it is showing that setuserName not a function in the browser
          props.setauthenticated(true);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          alert("Wrong email or password!! Try again");
        });
    }
  };
  //rest  of the code
export default Login;
```

In the child(Login) component I'm trying to set the username but its throwing error -> setuserName is not a function why? but I passed argumentsfrom the parent component with the same spelled still getting error, How?

I/musing Node version 18 and react version 18

Comment: You're using a component called `LoginSignup` (`import { LoginSignup } from "./MyComponent/LoginSignup";`), but you've shown the source code of a different component, `Login` (`export default Login;`). They're not only different names, but you're importing a named export, but exporting a default export. Is `LoginSignup` using `Login`? If so, does it pass the prop to it?